# identify user accross WP8 and Win8: ANID2 vs SafeCustomerId

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8, microsoft-account

We have a web service that needs to indentify a user accross his devices, wp8, and win8.

On the phone side we have `UserExtendedProperties.GetValue("ANID2")`, which get's the anonymous microsoft id.

On Windows8 there's `OnlineIdAuthenticator.AuthenticateUserAsync` with `UserIdentity.SafeCustomerId` and other properties, though none of them look like the ANID2.

The OnlineIdAuthenticator api exists on phone, but throws NotImplementedException.

Is there any way to get a common user identifier on win8 and wp8?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I know (it's apparently the recommended way too) is to use Azure Mobile Services (http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/home/scenarios/mobile-services/). There is a free plan that you can use.
With Mobile Services you can use the MobileServiceClient (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.mobileservices.mobileserviceclient.aspx) to get a unique ID for each user (based on the MS account).

This code gets the user ID:

```
MobileServiceClient client = new MobileServiceClient(serviceUri);
MobileServiceUser user = await client.LoginAsync(MobileServiceAuthenticationProvider.MicrosoftAccount);

/* The user ID contains the provider name and the ID seperated by a colon */
var userId = user.UserId.Split(':').Last();
```

You can find some more information here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj863454.aspx
and the SDK here: http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/developer-tools/

Comment: Thanks. One question, will this result in a login prompt(especially on the phone side)?

Comment: Yes, it opens a web page prompting the user to log-in. Looks like a standard OAuth page. Just like with OAuth there is no way to get the users password or email, so you can make a note of this before sending the user to the log-in page. If you want to see it in action check out Unification.