# Windows Phone - Get User ID

Tags: c#, windows-phone

I need to store and share a user's list of favorites across a Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight app, and a Windows 8.1 RT app. I have been using **Roaming Settings** up to this point, but it doesn't work for all connected devices. I have tested my app across a few devices and it syncs for most but not all devices. I have also received some user complaints about this too.

So instead I want to store a user's list of favorites in Azure Blob Storage, with the key being an anonymized user ID. But I can't seem to find any way of determining a user's ID. I have found information about `DeviceUniqueId` and there is `ID_cap_identify_user` capability in the manifest file for the Silverlight App (but not for the RT App) but I can't find any documentation on how to utilize this. Any help here would be apprciated.

PS - Does anyone have any theories as to why **Roaming Settings** isn't working correctly on some devices?

Answer (score 0):

There is an [UserInformationClass](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.system.userprofile.userinformation.aspx), BUT take note if you want to use it in reference to windows 10!

> If you have a Windows 8 app that uses the UserInformation class, you
>   should migrate your app to the Universal Windows Platform (UWP) and
>   access the User class instead. Universal Windows Platform (UWP) apps
>   that access user information are now expected to declare a new
>   capability, uap:userAccountInformation, and call new APIs,
>   Windows.System.User.FindAllAsync and User.GetPropertiesAsync, to get
>   the data.

There is also an MSDN example on how to use it: https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Account-picture-name-sample-912baff1

Comment: Thanks. It seems though that while I can use UserInformation for the RT version, it is not available for Silverlight.

Comment: Not sure it there is a common one for all, but for SilverLight you can look at this https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2013/03/11/migrating-anids-to-windows-phone-8/

Comment: Oh asked before it seems: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16063193/identify-user-accross-wp8-and-win8-anid2-vs-safecustomerid

Comment: Yep, I could use ANID2 for Silverlight, but I won't be able to pair this with anything from the UserInformation class that is available for RT. I checked the previous Stack Overflow post you mentioned - the main drawback of this is that requires a log-in prompt for the user on a web page, which will pull the user out of my app. Not a great user-experience.